# JavaScript Get Indexes based from the Selected Array of Object Id

Tags: javascript, arrays

Today, I'm trying to get the list of javascript index based from the selected data id that I have.

I'm following this guide from https://buefy.org/documentation/table/#checkable where it needs something like this: `checkedRows: [data[1], data[3]]` to able to check the specific row in the table.

What I need to do is to check the table based from my web API response.

I have this sample response data.

```
response.data.checkedRows // value is [{id: 1234}, {id: 83412}]
```

and I have the sample data from the table.

```
const data = [{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Jojo'
},{
    id: 43221,
    name: 'Jeff'
},{
    id: 83412,
    name: 'Kacey'
}]
```

So basically, I need to have something, dynamically, like this: `checkedRows: [data[0], data[2]]` because it matches the data from the `response.data.checkedRows`

So far, I tried using `forEach`

```
let selectedIndex = [];
response.data.checkedRows.forEach((d) => {
     this.data.forEach((e) => {
         if (d.id=== e.id) {
             // need the result to be dynamic depending on the response.data.checkedRows
             this.checkedRows = [data[0], data[2]]
         }
     });
});
```

I'm stuck here because I'm not sure how can I get the index that matches the selected checkedRows from response.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the response `checkedRows`, and in the callback, `.find` the matching object in the array:

```js
const checkedRows = [{id: 1234}, {id: 83412}];

const data = [{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Jojo'
},{
    id: 43221,
    name: 'Jeff'
},{
    id: 83412,
    name: 'Kacey'
}];

const objs = checkedRows.map(({ id }) => (
  data.find(obj => obj.id === id)
));
console.log(objs);
```

If there are a lot of elements, you can use a Set of the IDs to find instead to decrease the computational complexity:

```js
const checkedRows = [{id: 1234}, {id: 83412}];

const data = [{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Jojo'
},{
    id: 43221,
    name: 'Jeff'
},{
    id: 83412,
    name: 'Kacey'
}];

const ids = new Set(checkedRows.map(({ id }) => id));
const objs = data.filter(obj => ids.has(obj.id));
console.log(objs);
```

Comment: Both work. If you're not using a Set, you can filter the data by whether `.some` of the `checkedRows` has a matching ID, or you can map the `checkedRows` and `.find` the matching data element.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. But how can I get the index of the data based from my `response.data.checkedRows`  like this? and put it inside the local variable of `checkedBox`?

Comment: Like this `this.checkedRows = [data[0], data[2]]` but dynamically

Comment: Both snippets in my answer already result in the `[data[0], data[2]]` you're looking for - there's no need to find the indexes specifically, you just need the *matching objects*

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Thanks for the new learning @CertainPerformance. Stay safe!